# How can I get the coordinates of all the tiles of a polygon for every zoom level with leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on *leaflet* recently and I'd like to know if it is possible when I have a polygon drawn on my map to *get the coordinates (z/x/y) of the tiles* in which my polygon is, and this for *every zoom level*.

Right now, I'm working with the plugin boundary-canvas and I can obtain all those coordinates, but I have to change the zoom myself and move on the map to get all the tiles. I would like to have their coordinates with some calculations or something.

***Example :***

*zoom 1* : my polygon fits in one tile so I only get one z/x/y

*zoom 2* : the same

...

*zoom 6* : my polygon fits in 3 tiles, so I would get the coordinates of each tile.

etc... etc...

Comment: I'm gonna say https://github.com/mapbox/tile-cover

Comment: Thanks, now I'm gonna try to browserify it in order to make it work with my explorer.